# How to factorize equation of pair of lines?

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

> Find two equations of lines
> : $$6x^2 -xy -12y^2 -8x + 29y -14= 0$$

I tried doing it using quadratic equation but got some very much unusual value. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand and collect:

$$(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)=(ad)\ x^2 + (ae+bd)\ xy + (be)\ y^2 + (af+cd)\ x + (bf+ce)\ y + cf$$

Identifying coefficients leads to solving this system:

$\begin{cases}
ad=6\\
ae+bd=-1\\
be=-12\\
af+cd=-8\\
bf+ce=29\\
cf=-14\end{cases}$

You can try to work out integer solutions, since this is equal to $0$ there will be a proportionality coefficient, for instance try to start with $a=2,d=3$ or $c=2,f=-7$.

This is what I found:
$$(3x+4y-7)(2x-3y+2)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$6x^2-x(y+8)-(12y^2-29y+14)=0$$

The discriminant $(D)$ is $$(y+8)^2+24(12y^2-29y+14)=(17y-20)^2$$

$$\implies x=\dfrac{y+8\pm\sqrt D}{2\cdot6}$$

Answer (score 0):

***you can also partially diff. the equation
F(x,y)=` 6x2−xy−12y2−8x+29y−14
**strong text**
dF/dx=0                            ...(i)
dF/dy=0                            ...(ii)
(i) and(ii) will give unique linear equations.***

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.